# How to handle the list data validation error in document library sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Sharepoint has an exception SPListDatValidationException that is thrown when column data validation fails. Pretty neat thing as I can use it to find the fields causing the validation failure and customize the action i want to be done to it.

Now, document library with column validation will also throw a similar error, but the exception is of type SPException!!! First of all, I don't understand why microsoft sharepoint would have two different types of exceptions for the same issue =.=

Anyway, any suggestion as to how I can customize the action when data validation fails for document library with an SPException??